# Stored procedures call

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

If logged in user hasn't rights to modify tables(update,insert, etc). I has right to call some procedures that can insert, update data in tables.

So, are this procs will be called with my rights(I cant update,insert) or rights of that person, who created them and can do update, insert?

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server user(login) or user that has an access via front end/ user interface?

Comment: The permission check is not done for each statement inside a procedure. If a user does not have permission to insert into TableA but has permission to execute a procedure that inserts into TableA the procedure will work correctly and the data will be inserted.

Comment: That's true @SeanLange unless the CRUD operation is done in a database other than the one that the stored procedure resides in.

Comment: So procedure can insert into table only if it has permission to insert into table, am i right?

Comment: You don't give permissions to a procedure. You give permission to execute a procedure to a user. If the user has permission to execute the procedure the insert will happen regardless of the user's permission to the underlying table. This is all assuming you are within the same database as @Dave.Gugg pointed out.